# Key-Value-Pair, Column for each key, keys as columnheader

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I have a table field_list like this:

```
field_id|obj_id|field_key|field_content
----------------------------------------    
     1  |   1  |   123   |   Title_A
     2  |   1  |   234   |   IP_A
     3  |   1  |   567   |   DNS_A
     4  |   2  |   123   |   Title_B
     5  |   2  |   456   |   IP_B
     6  |   2  |   789   |   DNS_B
     7  |   3  |   123   |   Title_C
     8  |   3  |   456   |   IP_C
     9  |   3  |   789   |   DNS_C
```

What I need is this:

```
obj_id  |123    |456  |789
----------------------------------------    
    1   |Title_A|IP_A |DNS_A
    2   |Title_B|IP_B |DNS_B
    3   |Title_C|IP_C |DNS_C
```

I had several ideas, how to achieve this (create new table or view, use scirpts, etc.). Unfortunately my SQL-Skills are not very professional and I never know if I am working in the right direction.

Background:
The mySql database is used for storing information about webpages. There is a table 'obj', and a table 'field_list'. 'obj_id' is foreign-key from obj table. 'field_id' is primary-key from field_list.

I managed to get something that looks what I want with concatenate and seperators, but not as result with many columns.

If there is no easy answer, or to many - perhaps someone can lead me into the right direction.

Please excuse my bad english and grammar. This is my first stackoverflow question - I hope you have patience with me. I will modify my question tomorrow if something is not clear.

THX!

Comment: So what queries have you attempted thus far to achieve this result.  Do you actually need that sort of pivot result in the query itself, or can you simply read the results into a multi-dimensional array in your application layer?

Comment: MySQL does not support this kind of EAV relations on it's own. I would suggest you compile your table in your script rather than your SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this, but performance might not be perfect...

This table model excells in searching, not on it's table column representation:

```
SELECT object_id,
MAX( IF( field_key = 123, field_content, NULL) ) AS col_123,
MAX( IF( field_key = 234, field_content, NULL) ) AS col_234,
MAX( IF( field_key = 345, field_content, NULL) ) AS col_345,
MAX( IF( field_key = 456, field_content, NULL) ) AS col_456,
MAX( IF( field_key = 567, field_content, NULL) ) AS col_567
FROM field_list
GROUP BY object_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed what i need or at least asked for. I tested your query in SQL Fiddle and it works very nice [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e313/10/0]. I will try to solve my problem at work with this tomorrow. I found something similiar when I googled my problem but that solution did not work in my DB. I hope this helps me to figure out why. Thank you very much!

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e313/10/0

Comment: I figured out, that this does not work with my phpmyadmin but sql-workbench gives me the result I was looking for. Dunno why this does not work with my phpmyadmin instance. But thanks again for this fast and nice answer!

Comment: Strange. There schouldn't be a difference with phpMyAdmin... Anyways, glad I could help ;)

Comment: The reason why MAX IF did not work with phpmyadmin was missing privileges. Phpmyadmin was connecting with user root from localhost while sql-workbench was using a different user from another machine. If someone has the same problem, try altering the table 'user' and grant missing privileges.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to write out each and every field_key and column name using a LOOP and another table that has the key/column_name relationships?